# RIA Services metadata for entities in different class

Tags: silverlight, ria

In my project, I have the following:
- A class library that contains a Linq2SQL datacontext.
- A web project containing the domainservice that uses the datacontext in the library.

I've not found a way to add metadata to the services where I don't have to manually build all of the metadata elements myself. Is there some something I am missing?

I am using RIA Services 1.0 - if a service pack addresses this, I'd be happy to know about it.

Answer (score -1):

How to: Add Metadata Classes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.